# Bluetooth 5.0 problem in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, 21.04

I had used ubuntu 20.04 and now I am using ubuntu 21.04, but I don't know what is wrong with bluetooth, because my headphone i.e boat rockerz 550(bluetooth 5.0) is connecting, but sound is not coming from headphone, in pulseaudio output is not showing.

I have tried everything maybe ubuntu has issue with bluetooth 5.0
below error is occurring everytime:

> src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down

Can anybody provide a solution?